# Why is import { EMPTY } from 'rxjs' not working?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

```
import { EMPTY } from 'rxjs';
```

The following message is showed when I put the cursor over the word EMPTY:

```
The module "app-name/node_modules/RxJS/Rx" does not provide an export named 'EMPTY'.
```

===================

```
delObject(idObject) {

    this.idObjectSel = idObject;

    const result$ = this.alertService.showConfirm('Confirm', 'Are you sure?');
    result$.asObservable()
      .pipe(
      take(1),
      switchMap(result => result ? this.dbaccessService.delObjetId(idObject) : EMPTY)
    ) // pipe
      .subscribe(

      success => {
        this.getObject(localStorage.getItem('idUser'));
      },

      error => {
        this.alertService.showAlertDanger('Error trying to delete. Try again later');
      }

      ) // subscribe
  }
```

Comment: What is the RxJs version you are using?

Answer (score 0):

this import :

```js
import { EMPTY } from 'rxjs';
```

has been introduced in rxjs 6+ so you are probably using an older version.

**Solution 1** : Update rxjs to version 6 or later

**Solution 2** : Use this :

```js
import { empty } from "rxjs/observable/empty";
import { of } from "rxjs/observable/of";

//...

switchMap(result => result ? this.dbaccessService.delObjetId(idObject) : empty())

// or

switchMap(result => result ? this.dbaccessService.delObjetId(idObject) : of({}))
```